# Who can pray at the first queue?

Tags: salat, hadith, fatwa

It is said that Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him and his household declared some specialties or actually terms for the persons who intend to say their prayers (Salah/Namaz) at the first queue of Jama'a prayer. In the meanwhile, as a related hadith, I’ve heard a tradition (hadith) from Imam Muhammad-al-Baqir (a.s.) (الامام محمدالباقر علیه السلام) as the fifth Imam of Shia who said:

> the learned and good-tempered persons stand at the first queue …

I’m looking for relevant hadiths (traditions) concerning that. In other word I was wondering if there should be any special conditions or qualifications for the individuals who intend to say their prayers by standing at the first queue in Salah-al-Jama’ah?

*Note: I'd be appreciated if you respond it by referring to hadiths or scholars' rulings.*

Comment: Interesting question but I do not think we should stop anyone from praying in the first row if they reach before others...only Allah knows what lies in our hearts  :)

Comment: nice idea. god bless you

Answer (score 2):

According to sunni hadith collections and scholars:

There are rules for whom is the best to be chosen as an [Imam for congregation](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/348).

And there's a rule for how the queue's or rows should be held:
For example those of who are sedate and prudent should be in the first rows.

Also one can conclude from the hadith about whom should be an Imam that those people quoted their should be in the first rows, as the Imam should be the "best" among the congregation, anyone who would be more or less equal is worthy being "next" to him.

Here some other ahadith: narrated by [Abu Mas'ud](http://sunnah.com/muslim/4/134) and [ibn Mas'ud](http://sunnah.com/muslim/4/136) in Sahih Muslim (according [at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/80) it was reported also by Ubay ibn Ka'ab, Anas and al-Bara' (May Allah be  pleased with all of them)) and a [hadith](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/287) qualified as weak that boys should be at the last rows of man.

[Scholars (Arabic Fatwa)](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/163171) say that man should be at the first rows ordered according the narration from Sahih Muslim then boys then hermaphrodite and at the end woman (See [also in Arabic](http://aliftaa.jo/Question.aspx?QuestionId=2656)), but Imams shouldn't for example prohibit boys to pray in the first rows if they came to prayer earlier then men (because of this [hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/39/43))!

And Allah knows best!

Comment: Uh-huh, what you presented looks to be interesting for me (although your submitted response is based on dear Sunni brothers). جزاک الله خیرا

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhan o Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His Family and Companions

As you have asked for the Ahadith regarding specialities in people standing in first rows of Salah so here are some about specialities and Virtues

> Abu Mas'ud (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The Messenger of
>   Allah (ﷺ) used to gently pat our shoulders when we were standing in
>   rows at the time of Salat and say, "Keep (the rows) straight; do not
>   differ from each other lest your hearts should suffer from discord.
>   Let those of you who are **mature and prudent** (wise) be nearer to me, and
>   then those who are next to them."
>
> [Muslim].

And About Best of rows for  Men and Women

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The Messenger
>   of Allah (ﷺ) said, "The best of the men's rows (in Salat) is the first
>   row and the worst is the last; but the best of the woman's row is the
>   last and the worst of their rows is the first."
>
> [Muslim].

About Virtue for being in the first Row

> Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "If the people knew
>   what is the reward of making the call (for the prayer) and (of being
>   in) the first row (in the prayer), and if they found no other way to
>   get this privilege except by casting lots, they would certainly cast
>   lots for it. If they knew the reward of the noon prayer, they would
>   race for it, and if they knew the reward of the morning (i.e. Fajr)
>   and `Isha prayers, they would present themselves for the prayer even
>   if they had to crawl to reach there.(Bukhari)

and

> Al-Nu’man b. Bashir said: the prophet (ﷺ) used to straighten us in the
>   rows of prayer as the arrow is straightened, until he thought that we
>   had learned it from him and understood it. One day he turned towards
>   us, and shoulders in order, and say; Do not be irregular. And he would
>   say: Allah and his Angels bless those who near the first rows.(Sunan
>   Abi Dawud)

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.