# Why was I not allowed to pray in the first row?

Tags: salat, hadith, fiqh, beard

Today when i went to pray for maghrib, I sat on the first row. I have a habit of offering my prayers in the first row. For the past 1 year I am praying in the first row. As I sat down, the person next to me told me to move to the second row.

Now I am 18 years old, not a child.

> He also said that "First row is the ***RIGHT*** of the ones with a
>   beard and also because I was in half sleeves."

Now I do understand if they would move me back because of me wearing half sleeves (A few have said that it is better to wear full sleeves, I'm not sure on this matter ) but the part that got me confused was that **why was it the RIGHT of the ones with a beard**.

I just simply told him that i always pray in the first row and nobody has ever said something to me, so he let the matter go. The imaam then came and told me to go back, ofcourse i went back without any hesitation.

So please tell me, by referring to Authentic Hadiths and Quranic Verses, that if that man was right? Because the only hadith I am aware of on this matter is

> "If you were to know what the reward is for praying in the first row,
>   you would be fighting amongst yourselves for it"

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your inquirey: [Who can pray at the first queue?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28373/13438) might be somewhat relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The Hadith to be considered is:

> It was narrated that Jabir bin ‘Abdullah said: “The Messenger of Allah
>   (ﷺ) said: The best rows for men are the front rows and the worst rows
>   are the back rows, and the best rows for women are the back rows and
>   the worst are the front rows.”
>   [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1283490)

So before a ***prayer starts***, above is the recommended sequence.

Going a tangent about your point of not being a child at 18, I want to clarify that ***in Islam an individual is considered as an adult when he/she reaches puberty***. This can be as young as 7 or 8.

Once the Salah has started, any individual coming late should not move others into the back rows and occupy it themselves.

Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:

> When anyone amongst you stands up, and in the badltb transmitted on
>   the authority of Abu 'Awina, the words are:" He who stands in his
>   place and (goes away) and then comes back to it, he his the greatest
>   right (to occupy that).
>    [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/39/43)

Also refer to **[Who can pray at the first queue?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28373/who-can-pray-at-the-first-queue)**

Comment: I am still unclear if what that person said was correct or not? because i have never been told to move back. Also can you tell me if it is okay to pray in half sleeves?

Comment: W.r.t half sleeves, I'd recommend you ask it as a separate question to get more detailed answers. In short, it is mandatory to cover the awrah & the hands are NOT part of a man's awrah. But it is a sunnah to wear the best possible clothes when praying.